# How do you solve the packageNotFoundError in conda when trying to install google API SDK

Tags: google-api, sdk, conda

I am trying to install the google-api SDK in Anaconda prompt but I'm getting a error message `packageNotFoundError`. How do I solve this in my conda environment.

I was expecting the Google API SDK library to be installed in my conda environment after running the command `conda install -c conda-forge google-cloud-sdk`.